Which is the proper way to search inside a web page?
I have a picture for a mobile and wanted to identify its model and name. What I have done so far:
Using Delphi, I did a reverse image search via Google Lens:
https://lens.google.com/uploadbyurl?url=https://dz.foorshop.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/05/Samsung-M32-White-2.jpg

If you open the last link you will find some matches, My goal was to get the text that comes after "Related search" which identifies exact mobile model and name.

Next code worked well for the first image example:
var
 LHTTPClient: TNetHTTPClient;
 LResponse: IHTTPResponse;
 output: string;
 p1, p2: Integer;
begin
  LHTTPClient := TNetHTTPClient.Create(nil);
  try
    LHTTPClient.UserAgent := 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/125.0.0.0 Safari/537.36';
    LHTTPClient.AcceptLanguage := 'en-US,en;q=0.5';
    LHTTPClient.Accept :=  'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8';
    LResponse := LHTTPClient.Get('https://lens.google.com/uploadbyurl?url=https://dz.foorshop.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/05/Samsung-M32-White-2.jpg');
    SetLength(Output, LResponse.ContentLength);
    Output := LResponse.ContentAsString();
    
    // FINIDING A SIGNATURE TO RETREIVE RELATED SEARCH TEXT
    p1 := Pos('",["https://t2.gstatic.com/images?q', Output);
    p2 := p1;
    while p2 > 0 do
    begin
      Dec(p2);
      if Output[p2] = '"' then
      begin
        Result := Copy(Output, p2+1, p1 - p2-1);
        ShowMessage(Result);
        Break;
      end;
    end;
  finally
    LHTTPClient.Free;
  end;
end;

But when I change the image and try to search, that signature is not found. So I can't get the name!

https://lens.google.com/uploadbyurl?url=https://fdn2.gsmarena.com/vv/bigpic/samsung-galaxy-m32-5g-new.jpg

I know there other kind of search like using HTML parser, but tested many and all failed to find that text!
Any help is appreciated.

I believe the "related search" text is being generated via Javascript, so can't be obtained merely by grabbing the HTML from the link. You'll need to use a web engine that renders Javascript and then scrape that output.

Alcalade is right. That part of the web page is being built from a web script. Also bare in ind that its output may differ heavily from user to user. For instance if I try to open any of the links you supplied in your question none of them will generate web page that would contain the text you are looking for. That is probably because I leave in a totally different region os it is of no use for google of showing me same promoted content as it does for you. And that might be the main problem this doesn't always work for you.
